# Azure Function: do I have to use Premium plan's custom linux image feature, if I want to call a linux executable library in my nodejs function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm new to Azure so please excuse me if this is obvious.

I am building a Azure linux nodejs function that download zip files from Blob storage to local file system, unzip the file, and use a linux library called `GDCM` to extract information from the unzipped `.dicom` files, and finally upload the unzip files back to Blob storage.

In AWS Lambda, I was able to do this nicely by creating a layer for the lambda function:

> When you create a layer, you must bundle all content files of the
> library into a .zip file archive. You upload the .zip file archive to
> your layer from Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) or your
> local machine. Lambda extracts the layer contents into the `/opt`
> directory when setting up the execution environment for the function.

To achieve the same goal, do I need to build a custom linux image containing the GDCM linux library? This means I have to use the Premium plan.

Or Can I achieve the same goal by using the consumption plan?

Comment: Your function app project files can be uploaded to Azure using the zip deployment functionality of Azure Functions from a.zip (compressed) file[1]. Additionally, you can immediately execute your functions from the deployment package file.  This approach omits the deployment phase of moving files from the package to your function app's wwwroot directory. Instead, the Functions runtime mounts the package file, making the wwwroot directory's contents read-only.

Comment: Additionally, By adding WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE- 1 setting in your Function app configuration. This setting will execute your function from zipped package.

Comment: Utilizing your preferred tool, you may create a.zip package for your project and upload it to your function app in Azure. Push deployments can be started using Azure CLI. The command az functionapp deployment source config-zip pushes a.zip file to your function app.  Refer this document for zip deployment of azure functions -https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push.md

Comment: Regarding the GDCM library, you can upload the.zip package with the library files included to your function app. When configuring the function's execution environment, the library files will be extracted into the /opt directory.

Comment: You can follow these steps- In the project root directory for your function app, create a folder called bin.
To the bin folder, copy the GDCM library files.
Add the following line to the function.json file, replacing libgdcm.so with the name of the GDCM library file

Comment: function.json 

{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ],

"entryPoint": "MyNamespace.Function.Run",
"libraryPath": "/home/site/wwwroot/bin/libgdcm.so"

}

Comment: Using the tool of your choosing, create a.zip bundle for your project.
The.zip package should be uploaded to your function app in Azure.
When configuring the function's execution environment, the library files will be extracted and placed in the /opt directory.

Comment: @SiddheshDesai  Thank you for the detailed comments. I'm happy to mark it as accepted answer if you can make it an answer post

Comment: Glad it was helpful, I Posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comments as an answer for community.

- Your function app project files can be uploaded to Azure using the zip deployment functionality of Azure Functions from a.zip (compressed).  Additionally, you can immediately execute your functions from the deployment package file. This approach omits the deployment phase of moving files from the package to your function app's wwwroot directory. Instead, the Functions runtime mounts the package file, making the wwwroot directory's contents read-only.  And after that add `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE- 1` setting in your Function app configuration. This setting will execute your function from zipped package.
- Utilizing your preferred tool, you may create a.zip package for your project and upload it to your function app in Azure. Push deployments can be started using Azure CLI. The command

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resource_group> -n \
<app_name> --src <zip_file_path>
```

[image]

Refer this [**document**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push.md) for zip deployment of azure functions.

Regarding the GDCM library, you can upload the.zip package with the library files included to your function app. When configuring the function's execution environment, the library files will be extracted into the /opt directory.

**You can follow these steps-**

In the project root directory for your function app, create a folder called bin.

You can visit the root directory of your function app by creating your Function app in Kudu Console:-

[image]

To the bin folder, copy the GDCM library files. Add the following line to the function.json file, replacing libgdcm.so with the name of the GDCM library file like below:-

**function.json**

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ],

"entryPoint": "MyNamespace.Function.Run",
"libraryPath": "/home/site/wwwroot/bin/libgdcm.so"

}
```

Using the tool of your choice, create a.zip bundle for your project. The.zip package should be uploaded to your function app in Azure. When configuring the function's execution environment, the library files will be extracted and placed in the /opt directory.

**One alternative is to dockerize your Function app and install the custom linux library in an Azure Function docker file and deploy it.**

Comment: A follow up question: the GDCM library files consists of 2 parts: 1. the binary executable file `gdcmscanner` and 2. the dynamic library files (by running `ldd gdcmscanner`, I can see them).  So how should I put them in my project?  Do I place them all under `<project root directory>/bin/`?

Comment: Yes, You can add the gdcm library files with binary executable gdcmscanner and dynamic files in <project root directory>/bin/ after copying all the files in the bin folder edit your function.json like I have given in the answer

Comment: Do I need to manually somehow "link" the `gdcmscanner` file and the dynamic library files? Sorry this must be a rookie linux question. But how is the `gdcmscanner` file supposed to find the dynamic lib files?

Comment: You don't need to link the gdcmscanner and dynamic files manually. Once you upload the zip package with library files in your function app the library files will be extracted to /opt directory. Then the gdcmscanner file will find the dynamic file automatically as it will be placed in /opt directory which is the default path for shared libraries.

Comment: Thus you can place all files GDCM executables, binary files and dynamic file inside <project root directory>/bin. Later you can access those file by SSH'ing into the Function app via kudu console

Comment: A follow up:  In the Azure Functions 4.0 runtime, the `function.json` is no longer required. How to achieve the same goal as specifying the `libraryPath` without the `function.json` file then?

Comment: Then the only option is to put the dependencies in a folder inside functions app project directory that will be deployed together as a code, You can then access those dependency as mentioned in this document- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/bring-dependency-to-functions.md

Comment: Hi, I created an Azure function with 3.0 runtime and did exactly as you suggested. But the lib files in `/bin` are not found in `/opt` in KUDU console after completing the zip deployment of the function. I must have missed something very basic. I have a summary in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76922973/running-a-third-party-linux-library-in-azure-function  Could you please take a look?