# How to call a ubuntu library / bash executable in my Azure Linux Nodejs Function?

Tags: azure-functions

In my Azure Linux Nodejs Function running nodejs code, I need to call a ubuntu library / bash executable.

This is the library I want to use:

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/man1/gdcmscanner.1.html
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/kinetic/+package/libgdcm-tools

Now, how can I install this ubuntu package in my Azure function environment and use them in the Azure function nodejs code?

Please give some outlines

Comment: This question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76778546/3703783