# Running a third party Linux library in Azure Function

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, azure-functions

I have been working on Azure function for quite some time now and this post will be pretty long.
I will summarize some methods I found about running a third party Linux library in Azure Function and the problems I am facing.

To describe the background, I am building a linux nodejs azure function that when processing a task, downloads a `.zip` file (which contains many `.dicom` files) from Azure Blob Storage, unzip it. And then using a linux library called `libgdcm-tools`, run an executable command `gdcmscanner` to analyze and extract information from all the `.dicom` files that are unzipped.

Here is how I would install the `libgdcm-tools` lib in linux:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install -y cmake g++ git
sudo apt install -y libgdcm-tools
```

After installation, here is the command to iterate through all `.dicom` files in a directory, and extract information from them:

```
gdcmscanner -t 20,11 -d path_to_folder_containing_files/ -r -p
```

Now,
I am running an Azure Function with 3.0 runtime and I need to execute the above task.

There are a few ways to do it:

**Option 1**:

Refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76778546/3703783

The idea is:

- Use Zip Deployment to deploy the nodejs function.
- In the project root directory for the function app, create a folder called /bin.
- To the bin folder, copy the GDCM library files:

```
john@MacBook-Pro:~/code/azure_function/bin$ tree . 
.
├── gdcmscanner  // this is the executable 
├── libc.so.6
├── libcharls.so.2
├── libcrypto.so.1.1
├── libdl.so.2
├── libexpat.so.1
├── libgcc_s.so.1
├── libgdcmCommon.so.3.0
├── libgdcmDICT.so.3.0
├── libgdcmDSED.so.3.0
├── libgdcmIOD.so.3.0
├── libgdcmMSFF.so.3.0
├── libgdcmjpeg12.so.3.0
├── libgdcmjpeg16.so.3.0
├── libgdcmjpeg8.so.3.0
├── libjson-c.so.5
├── libm.so.6
├── libopenjp2.so.7
├── libpthread.so.0
├── libstdc++.so.6
├── libuuid.so.1
└── libz.so.1
```

`gdcmscanner` is the executable file, and the rest are its dynamic library files.

- Edit the following line to the function.json file:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/sealworker/index.js",
  "libraryPath":"/home/site/wwwroot/bin/gdcmscanner"
}
```

- upload the.zip package with the library files included to your function app. When configuring the function's execution environment, the library files will be extracted into the `/opt` directory.

And in the nodejs code:

```
const util = require("util");
const exec = util.promisify(require("child_process").exec);

...

  const cmd = `/opt/bin/gdcmscanner -t 20,11 -t 18,1030 -t 08,60 -t 18,15  -t 20,13 -d ${directoryPath} -r -p`;
  const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(cmd, {
    maxBuffer: 100 * 1024 * 1024
  });
```

Ideally this should work, however I was not able to make it work:

**Issue**:

When testing in Azure function app, it complains:

```
2023-08-17T10:24:08Z   [Information]   Error: Command failed: /opt/bin/gdcmscanner -t 20,11  -d /data/issues/c1d55b3ccb137039/raw/unzipped_files -r -p
/bin/sh: 1: /opt/bin/gdcmscanner: not found
```

And I have SSH'ed into the Function app via kudu console. The library files in `/bin` is not extracted into the `/opt` directory:

```
root@b0cdac0c05d7:/opt# pwd
/opt
root@b0cdac0c05d7:/opt# ls
root@b0cdac0c05d7:/opt#
```

`/opt` is empty, and as expected, I still see `/bin/sh: 1: /opt/bin/gdcmscanner: not found` error.

**Option 2**:

according to this doc: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/bring-dependency-to-functions.md, put the dependencies in a folder inside functions app project directory that will be deployed together as a code:

```
<project_root>/
 | - my_first_function/
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | | - example.py
 | - dependencies/
 | | - dependency1
 | - .funcignore
 | - host.json
 | - local.settings.json
```

I haven't tried this yet, but I have two questions:

1. Do I put all these files:

```
.
├── gdcmscanner  // this is the executable 
├── libc.so.6
├── libcharls.so.2
├── libcrypto.so.1.1
├── libdl.so.2
├── libexpat.so.1
├── libgcc_s.so.1
├── libgdcmCommon.so.3.0
├── libgdcmDICT.so.3.0
├── libgdcmDSED.so.3.0
├── libgdcmIOD.so.3.0
├── libgdcmMSFF.so.3.0
├── libgdcmjpeg12.so.3.0
├── libgdcmjpeg16.so.3.0
├── libgdcmjpeg8.so.3.0
├── libjson-c.so.5
├── libm.so.6
├── libopenjp2.so.7
├── libpthread.so.0
├── libstdc++.so.6
├── libuuid.so.1
└── libz.so.1
```

into `<project_root>/dependencies/dependency1`?

2. Since they are not in the `/opt` directory, Do I need to manually somehow "link" the `gdcmscanner` file and the dynamic library files? How?

**Option 3**:

This is the temporary method that I was able to at least get working:

- After I complete zip deployment, I simply SSH'ed into the Function app via kudu console and manually install the lib:

```
root@b0cdac0c05d7:/# apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt install -y cmake g++ git && apt install -y libgdcm-tools

...

root@b0cdac0c05d7:/# which gdcmscanner 
/usr/bin/gdcmscanner
root@b0cdac0c05d7:/#
```

And then when I test the azure function, it was able to at least execute the `gdcmscanner` command. It complains about the file though:

```
0905/000177.dcm (could not be read)\n',
  'Filename: /data/issues/c1d55b3ccb137039/raw/zip_decompressed/000237.dcm (could not be read)\n',
  ... 141 more items
]
```

But this is no longer a linux lib installation issue.

For this method, the problem is that everytime I update the function and do zip deployment again, I need to manually install again.

Should I find some way to automatically install and settle with this method?

I would prefer to go with one of the previous options though.

There is the alternative to dockerize the Function app and install the custom linux library in an Azure Function docker file and deploy it. But I still want to get the first 2 options clear first

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

OK. An answer to myself:

**Option 2 worked well:**

- Where to put the files: all those files would go into `<project\_root>/dependencies/dependency1`.
- Linking the gdcmscanner file: When executing a binary that has shared library dependencies, the loader uses the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to locate those shared libraries. Set this variable before executing  command. For example:

```
  const path_to_dependencies = "/home/site/wwwroot/dependencies/gdcm";
  const cmd = `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${path_to_dependencies} /home/site/wwwroot/dependencies/gdcm/gdcmscanner -t 20,11 -t 18,1030 -t 08,60 -t 18,15  -t 20,13 -d ${directoryPath} -r -p`;
```

This way, when gdcmscanner is invoked, it will look for its shared libraries in the directory.